# Re-entering UK on a 6-months, multiple entry Standard Visitor (tourist) visa

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens

I have a UK multiple entry tourist visa valid for six months. I have traveled once to London for a week. I want to visit Scotland and London again.

Can I use the same visa as it will expire in November?

Can I take the journey before that?

What do I need to do?

Comment: I really don't understand the question.  You have a multiple entry visa, and you want to know whether you can use it more than once?  Why wouldn't you be able to?  It's like asking, "I bought a one-day transit pass in city X and used it to travel from my hotel to the museum this morning.  Can I now use it to travel from the museum to the theater?"  Or, more generally, "I have item X, which is intended for purpose Y.  Can I use it for purpose Y?"

Comment: I mean that do I need to go for restamping or should i inform the High commission again before I atke teh visist.

Comment: You do not need to go for restamping.  You will get a new stamp in your passport when you cross the border.  You do not need to give advance notice of your intention to reuse the visa.  That's why it was multiple entry.  If they wanted advance notice of a subsequent visit, they would have given you a single-entry visa.